# MongoClient library not found on CLI wamp

Tags: php, mongodb, command-line-interface, database

I am using PHP 5.4.3 on wamp(local) and mongodb. When i run script from browser then it runs fine. but when i try to run it from command prompt (CLI). It gives me fatal error like 'Mongo class not found'.

Can anyone suggested me what i have done wrong here.

Thanks
Ashsih Goyal

Answer (score 1):

Look at output of `php -i`, "Loaded Configuration File" will tell you which ini file is used. Add the dll there.

Comment: I have tried it but it the file's output too long. So i am not able to check the output. Can you please let me know how can i check it

Comment: php -i |grep "Loaded Configuration File"

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have opened the php.ini file from where my configuration file loads and i have added the extension in php.ini and it shows me on phpinfo (browser). But it doesn't show the mongo extension on CLI

Answer (score 0):

Friend In Wamp for Browser based request WAMP uses php.ini stored with apache mostly found in apache directry(search there) and Command Line based request are directly made with php.exe and php.ini will found in same directory in which php.exe so enable modules in that ini which you wants in command line.